# navigator.onLine boolean attribute

Tags: javascript, html, google-material-icons

Is there an answer to my question?
I want to use `(navigator.onLine)` to detect if the user is online/offline by using google's material icons. I've tried this already but it doesn't work.
Here's some code to start with:

```
<p id="onlineoffline"><span class="material-icons">
signal_wifi_connected_no_internet_4
</span></p>
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Instead of text, I want to use material icons to indicate if the user is online/offline

Comment: have you tried wifi_off?

Comment: Is it the material icon that is not displaying? is it the 'offline'/'online' event not firing on the window? You need to be clear of what the problem is and what errors you are getting (if any)

Comment: Yea, The icon is not displaying and just displays the default or unknown text.